# htaccess <Directory> deny from all

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I've been cleaning up my project lately. I have a main .htaccess in the root directory and 6 others. 5 of them ran `Options -Indexes` which i didn't see anypoint of allowing any Directory viewing so moved that to the main one. so now i only have 2 .htaccess files. the main and one in `/system` which holds

```
# Block External Access
deny from all
```

So i wanted to run that on `/system` only from within the main. So i deleted the one in /system and added

```
 # Block External Access
<Directory "/system/">
deny from all
</Directory>
```

to my main .htaccess file leaving 1!

but now i get a

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@localhost and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) Server at 10.0.1.5 Port 80

The goal is to block reading any files in /system and it's sub directory's but allow viewing of everything else all from one `.htaccess` file for the whole project. Any ideas on how i can fix this? I did some Google searches but couldn't really come out with anything.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You cannot use the [Directory directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directory) in .htaccess.  However if you create a .htaccess file in the /system directory and place the following in it, you will get the same result

```
#place this in /system/.htaccess as you had before
deny from all
```

Comment: Yeah. I had a .htaccess placed in /system before. Was just trying to have only one for the whole project. Guess i can't and will have to do it that way.

Comment: for windows users , make sure you make the file name exactly `.htaccess` by save-as the file from some text editor because windows explorer doesn't allow you to remove file names. it was a problem for me

Comment: You can create `.htaccess` files and other file starting with dot characted on Windows in file explorer. Simply name it `.htaccess.`, the dot at end **disables checking if name starts with dot** (it is automatically removed).

Answer (score 15):

You can also use RedirectMatch directive to deny access to a folder.

To deny access to a folder, you can use the following RedirectMatch in htaccess :

```
 RedirectMatch 403 ^/folder/?$
```

This will forbid an external access to /folder/ eg : http://example.com/folder/ will return a 403 forbidden error.

To deny access to  everything inside the folder, You can use this :

```
RedirectMatch 403 ^/folder/.*$
```

This will block access to the entire folder eg : http://example.com/folder/anyURI will return a 403 error response to client.

Comment: @Anthony This works perfectly fine on all versions of Apache . I had tested it on my local and live server before posting here. Are you sure the server you are using is Apache ? Also make sure to use this  code at the top of your htaccess before other rules you may have in your htaccess otherwise the directive will be ignored.

Comment: Yes it is apache...  however   "RewriteRule ^folder/ - [F,L]"  does work fine.

Comment: Arhhh... The directory URI is NOT on the top level, but after adding the full URI path, it did work fine.   HOWEVER I would not want to encode the URL path in a ".htaccess" file if at all possible!  Directories move around, and the URI path should NOT be needed in ".htaccess" file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use from root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(?:system)\b.* /403.html
```

Or:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:system)\b.* /403.php # with header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
```

Comment: Add to ".htaccess"    "RewriteRule ^folder/ - [F,L]"
Yes you will see a directory redirection ( for the '/' on end) but that redirection then fails.   It also seems to remove it from the auto-index list!