# Insert HTML code in all pages via Apache?

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I don't know if Apache or `.htaccess` is the right way, but I like to know how to insert an HTML code to all pages inside a `public_html` directory, kinda like free hosts in the early 2000s where they insert their banner in all pages.

Note: I am not talking about manually editing each page and adding `SSI` or PHP's `include()`

Comment: You have prepend and append: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file

Comment: check this http://serverfault.com/questions/46449/how-to-inject-html-code-into-every-delivered-html-page

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following method to insert HTML code to all pages within a specific directory using `.htaccess`:

```
<Directory "/public_html/">
    # Prepend to top
    php_value auto_prepend_file "/dir/path/banner.php"

    # Append to bottom
    php_value auto_append_file "/dir/path/footer.php"
</Directory>
```

The following article discusses how .htaccess can allow you to prepend/append html to every page request:

http://davidwalsh.name/prepend-append-files-htaccess

The following article discusses how to use the .htaccess directory block:

[htaccess <Directory> deny from all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683496/htaccess-directory-deny-from-all)

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Will this also inject the footer in si folders of ‘public_html’ with that directive?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a custom output filter using ExtFilterDefine and SetOutputFilter and have that run a PHP script which reads stdin:// then inserts the code you want and outputs it.  Check out http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ext_filter.html to get started.

If you're just concerned with PHP output and not static HTML files as well, you could use auto_prepend_file to run a script which calls `ob_start()`, and auto_append_file to run a script which calls `$html = ob_get_clean()` and inserts the code into $html before echoing it out.

Answer (score 0):

i can insert html to all pages via Apache, but only for site that hosted by my apache, not all site though my apache proxy server.

this is how it work.
i set up an XAMPP, download mod_layout 5.1 for apache 2.4. (install mod_layout is simple, if you use XAMPP for windows, just download mod_layout.so 5.1 for windows and put it to your apache module folder $home/apache/module, then add the config DSO to your httpd.conf LoadModule layout_module modules/mod_layout.so - if you using linux or other os, you should download mod_layout.so for linux, then run make command to install)

After install mod_layout.so for windows, just put this code on your .htaccess file or httpd.conf your will get html insert to all your page:

```
<IfModule mod_layout.c>
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT html 
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT htm 
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT shtml 
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT shtm 
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT cgi 
AddOutputFilter LAYOUT php 
LayoutFooter "C:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin/footer.php"
</IfModule>
```

C:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin/footer.php is where you put your html or php file, in my situation is C:/xampp/apache/cgi-bin/footer.php, but you can put it any where, just give the right path, you'll be fine